# @Autowired session scope bean not pointing to same instance

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I got this weird situation in Autowiring the bean in spring. First I declare this bean;

```
<beans:bean id="customerInfo" class="my.web.app.com.CustomerInfoSession" scope="session" >
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</beans:bean>
```

And there are two case when I set the value in **customerInfo**;

First I set like this:

```
SqlRowSet srs =jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(query, qparams);
    if (srs.isBeforeFirst()==true) {
        while (srs.next()) {
            customerInfo.setLoginId(srs.getString("LOGINID"));
            customerInfo.setCompanyId(srs.getString("COMPANYID"));
        }
    }
System.out.println("Instance : "+customerInfo);//for first pointing check
```

Then I check the Autowiring pointer in another class by @Autowired the bean;

in Test class:

```
@Controller
public class Test {

@Autowired
private CustomerInfoSession customerInfo;

public void checkObject(){
System.out.println("Call back : "+customerInfo);//for second pointing check
}

}
```

**Result**:

> Instance : my.web.app.com.CustomerInfoSession@1e7c92cc
>
> Call back :my.web.app.com.CustomerInfoSession@1e7c92cc

As we can see,the @Autowiring is calling the same bean instance as it should be, but the problem came when I change to set the value like this:

```
customerInfo = (CustomerInfoSession) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query,qparam,new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CustomerInfoSession.class));
System.out.println("Instance : "+customerInfo);//for first pointing check
```

By using the same Test class,the **Result** is:

> Instance : my.web.app.com.CustomerInfoSession@2d700bd6
>
> Call back :my.web.app.com.CustomerInfoSession@5e33e39c

As we can see,the @Autowired not pointing to the same instance...

Why using different jdbc template affect the @Autowired session scope bean?

Why the bean is not pointing to same instance like is should be?

Comment: I don't understand. In the first case, The Spring context gives you an object.  In the second case, the `JdbcTemplate` presumably fetches some data from a database and creates and returns a different object. Where is your confusion?

Comment: @Pillar ,the first case, I set the `customerInfo` property one by one using the setter from the SqlRowSet result I got by fetching from database, the second case, I set the `customerInfo` directly using BeanPropertyRowMapper that return the `customerInfo` instance with their property already set up using BeanPropertyRowMapper, my confusion is the bean is not using same instance when I set the object directly but it work perfectly when I set the property manually. Sorry long comment...

Comment: Your second one overrides the session scoped proxy and is basically destroying your session scoped object and it now is suddenly a singleton object. So basically what you are doing in the second part is wrong and dangerous and must be avoided.

Comment: @M.Deinum ,actually I thought `@Autowired` will refer to the new bean reference,but is not. I just want to simplify the code after all. If you have any approach that can simplify the bean set property,I will appreciate if you share it,btw Thanks! ,for pointing that out .

Comment: `@Autowired` is for wiring bean instances at startup time, not runtime and it will not *outject* dependencies magically to other instances. Just write a `RowMapper` that sets the properties instead of using the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first scenario, you are setting the properties on the object injected by the Spring.

But in the next case, `jdbcTemplate` is creating a new instance of `CustomerInfoSession` object you have pointed the `customerInfo` object ref to point to this newly created object.

The below statement

> customerInfo = (CustomerInfoSession) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query,qparam,new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CustomerInfoSession.class));

is effectively equivalent to

> CustomerInfoSession temp = (CustomerInfoSession)
>   jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, qparam,
>                 new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CustomerInfoSession.class));
>
> customerInfo = temp;

To visualize (click on the below images to view it better),

**In Case 1:**

[image]

**In Case 2:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks !So its creating a new instance. I thought that BeanPropertyRowMapper can simplify my code. Do you have any approach you can share to simplify the jdbctemplate database fetching other than my first method?